# How can i filter css selection by id?

Tags: jquery

I am trying to use jquery to filter the css selection by id but its not allowing me to. Below is the code I am using. Any help would be really appreciated. Thanks!

```
$(".working:[id=302750]")
```

Comment: Could you try this `$(".working").filter("[id='302750']");`

https://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/make-an-jquery-hasattr/

Comment: Why not just query directly by ID? `$("#302750")`

Comment: @Phil i didnt think of that lol thanks